# Detect when volume buttons are pressed

Tags: macos, audio, keyboard-shortcuts, volume

I have the problem that I can't change the volume on my Mac when connected to my Onkyo-AV via HDMI. My idea now is to capture when the volume buttons are pressed on the Mac and execute a script that changes the volume of the AV. I already searched a lot for capturing global keys but couldn't find a solution to when the volume button is pressed.

**Is this possible with a script? Or how could I achieve this?**

Comment: Maybe you could run this once a second in Terminal... `osascript -e 'output volume of (get volume settings)'` There's another one called `output muted of (get volume settings)` or somesuch.

Comment: The problem is, that the volume is not changing. As output of `get volume settings` I get always `volume:missing value, input volume:50, alert volume:100, output muted:missing value`.